# No auto-redirect on IdentityServer3 logout endpoint

Tags: javascript, c#, cors, identityserver3, openid-connect

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I've gotten almost everything working in identity server 3 and I don't consider myself a novice there but I'm really having a hard time auto-redirecting from a javascript application to my chosen redirect URL after using a generated link to logout. Some things have been omitted for brevity (such as the full jwt token).

Here is my request:

```
https://identity.mysite.com/id/connect/endsession?id_token_hint=jwt-id-token&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/
```

Here is the client config:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientName = "Website User",
                ClientId = "webuser",
                Flow = Flows.AuthorizationCode,
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>()
                {
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Auth:CorsOriginPrimary"),
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Auth:CorsOriginSecondary"),
                },
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Auth:RedirectUri"),
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Auth:SecondaryRedirectUri"),
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Auth:TertiaryRedirectUri")
                },
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("WebUser:Secret").Sha256())
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Auth:WebPostLogoutUri"),
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Auth:WebPostLogoutUri:Local")
                },
                AllowAccessToAllScopes = true
            },
```

Here's the factory config (CORS) stuff:

```
var corsPolicy = new DefaultCorsPolicyService
            {
                AllowedOrigins = new[]
                {
                    "https://storageurl.blob.core.windows.net",
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Auth:CorsOriginPrimary"),
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Auth:CorsOriginSecondary")
                },
                AllowAll = true
            };
```

Of course AllowAll = true was really just me trying to get it working.

Here are the relevant config entries:

```
    <add key="Auth:RedirectUri" value="http://localhost:3000/_oauth/oidc/" />
    <add key="Auth:SecondaryRedirectUri" value="http://mysiteloc.com:3000/_oauth/oidc" />
    <add key="Auth:TertiaryRedirectUri" value="http://localhost:3000/_oauth/oidc"  />
    <add key="Auth:CorsOriginPrimary" value="http://localhost:3000" />
    <add key="Auth:CorsOriginSecondary" value="http://mysiteloc.com:3000" />
    <add key="Auth:WebPostLogoutUri" value="http://localhost:3000/" />
    <add key="Auth:WebPostLogoutUri:Local" value="http://mysiteloc:3000/" />
```

And then here's the logs. It looks like something might be wrong with CORS, but I'm not sure. I'd have thought that allowing the origins in the factory config and the client config would be enough but I'm still getting issues.

```
2017-01-30 16:52:14.2034 INFO: Redirecting to logout page
2017-01-30 16:52:14.2465 INFO: Logout prompt for subject: 2054e687-777b-4ca3-bb20-ee59d8a1dc28
2017-01-30 16:52:14.2465 INFO: EnableSignOutPrompt set to false, performing logout
2017-01-30 16:52:14.2465 INFO: Logout endpoint submitted
2017-01-30 16:52:14.2465 INFO: Logout requested for subject: 2054e687-777b-4ca3-bb20-ee59d8a1dc28
2017-01-30 16:52:14.2465 INFO: Clearing cookies
2017-01-30 16:52:14.2580 INFO: rendering logged out page
2017-01-30 16:52:14.5831 INFO: CSP Report endpoint requested
2017-01-30 16:52:14.5831 INFO: CSP Report data: {"csp-report":{"document-uri":"https://identity.mysite.com/id/logout","referrer":"http://localhost:3000/reservations/purchase","violated-directive":"script-src 'self' ","effective-directive":"script-src","original-policy":"default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; img-src *; font-src 'self' https://storageurl.blob.core.windows.net/; report-uri https://identity.mysite.com/id/csp/report","blocked-uri":"eval","line-number":174,"column-number":361,"source-file":"https://identity.mysite.com/id/assets/scripts.2.5.0.js","status-code":0}}
2017-01-30 16:52:14.5831 INFO: Rendering 204
2017-01-30 16:52:14.7738 INFO: End session callback requested
2017-01-30 16:52:14.7738 DEBUG: No client end session iframe URLs
```

Anything you can help me out with would be amazing. I've thought that maybe I need to pass the Authorization Code instead of the actual ID token here, but I've seen other examples where they pass the ID Token and it works fine. What am I missing?

Edit: When looking at the network tab in Chrome, it also looks like the original endsession endpoint redirects me to endsessioncallback?sid=[some-sort-of-id]. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Another thought - when I submit the id_token_hint parameter, do I need to include what type of token it is? For example do I need the "Bearer " designation in front of the token?

Comment: No, just the id_token as a jwt.

Answer (score 0):

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/authenticationOptions.html

EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect (default: false) ?

If you haven't touched this property in your options, might be this.

Comment: This property is already set to true, but hasn't made a difference. Thanks though!

Comment: Then you need to provide a bit more detail to get to understand what you're experiencing. 

How do you redirect to https://identity.mysite.com/id/connect/endsession ? 
windows.location = yoururl ? 

What happens if you do enter the endsession url manually by just opening a new tab and enter the id_token and the url manually? Do you see the logout screen at all or does it fail?


Considering you were talking about CORS, it does sounds like you're doing something wrong. CORS is not relevant unless you do a AJAX call instead of a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Right now it's simply window.location = yoururl. If there is a better way to signout via ajax I'd love to do that since the user is wanting to logout anyway and I don't really care that much about showing them any feedback from the identity server.